# caught ReferenceError: route is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertia

При создании запроса в базу данных выводит ошибку **route is not defined** на **book-screen__download.vue:48:10**. Проект на гитхабе https://github.com/chikbob/botan-cultire-master

Код **book-screen__download.vue:**

```
<template>
    <section :class="cnBookScreen('download')">
        <div :class="cnBookScreen('download-block')">
            <div :class="cnBookScreen('download-text')">
                {{ model.book.name }}
            </div>
            <button @click="isOpen = true" :class="cnBookScreen('download-btn')">
                Завантажити
            </button>
            <form @submit.prevent="store">
                <BookScreenDialogRegistration :open="isOpen" @close="isOpen = !isOpen">
                    <div @click="isOpen = false" :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-dialog_exit')">X</div>
                    <div :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-dialog_content')">Заповніть дані, щоб отримати електронну
                        копію
                    </div>
                    <div :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-input_text')">Ім’я</div>
                    <input v-model="form.name" :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-input')" required />
                    <div :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-input_text')">Номер телефону</div>
                    <input v-model="form.telephone" :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-input')" required />
                    <div :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-input_text')">Електронна пошта</div>
                    <input v-model="form.email" :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-input')" required />

                    <button @click="isClosed()" :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-btn')">Завантажити</button>
                </BookScreenDialogRegistration>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { cnBookScreen } from "./book-screen.const.js";
import { bookModel } from "./book-screen.model.js";
import BookScreenDialogRegistration from './book-screen__dialogRegistration.vue'
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const model = bookModel();

const isOpen = ref(false)

const form = useForm({
    name: null,
    telephone: null,
    email: null
});

function store() {
    form.post(route('Visitor/index'))
}

function isClosed() {
    isOpen = false
}

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.book-screen__dialogRegistration {
    &-dialog {
        &_exit {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;

            font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 15px;

            margin: 0.5rem auto 20px 96%;

            width: fit-content;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;

            color: #8FBC76;

            padding: 0.3rem;

            border-radius: 2rem;

            &::selection {
                background: transparent;
            }

            &::-moz-selection {
                background: transparent;
            }

        }

        &_content {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;

            font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: center;

            width: 60%;

            margin: 10px auto 20px;

            color: #222E21;
        }
    }

    &-btn {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;

        font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 48px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        padding: 0 25px;

        border-radius: 50px;

        margin: 30px auto 60px;

        height: fit-content;

        background-color: #8FBC76;
        color: #fff;

        cursor: pointer;
    }

    &-input {
        width: 300px;
        height: 30px;

        margin: auto;

        &_text {
            font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: flex-start;

            margin: 10px auto;

            width: 300px;
            color: #222E21;
        }
    }
}

.book-screen__download {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 60px;

    &-block {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;

        width: 540px;
        height: 260px;

        border: 7px #8eba75 solid;
    }

    &-text {
        font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;

        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto 35px;

        color: #222E21;
    }

    &-btn {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;

        font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 48px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        padding: 10px 25px;

        border-radius: 50px;

        height: fit-content;

        background-color: #8FBC76;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
</style>
```

Код импортированного **book-screen__dialogRegistration.vue**

```
<template>
    <div :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration')" v-show="open">
        <div :class="cnBookScreen('dialogRegistration-content')">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { cnBookScreen } from "./book-screen.const.js";
import { bookModel } from "./book-screen.model.js";

const model = bookModel();

const props = defineProps({
    open: Boolean,
    required: Boolean,
})

console.log(props.open)

function hideDialog(open) {
    open = false
    console.log(open)
    return open
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.book-screen__dialogRegistration {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 100;

    &-content {
        margin: auto;
        background: #EDF6E2;
        border-radius: 15px;
        min-width: 700px;
        min-height: 400px;

        z-index: 100;

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
</style>
```

**Миграция** в бд выглядит так:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('visitors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('telephone');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
};
```

И код **VisitorController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Pages;

use Inertia\Inertia;
use Inertia\Response;
use App\Models\Visitor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VisitorController
{

    public function __invoke(Visitor $visitor): Response
    {
        return Inertia::render('Visitor/index', [
            'visitors' => Visitor::all(),
        ]);
    }
    
    public function store(Request $request) 
    {
        Visitor::create($request->validate([
                'name' => ['required', 'max:50'],
                'telephone' => ['required', 'max:50'],
                'email' => ['required', 'max:50', 'email'],
        ]));

        return to_route('visitor.index');
    }
}
```

И вот все **роуты** на страницах

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Pages\BookPageController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Pages\VisitorController;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('index');
});

Route::get('/books/{book}', BookPageController::class);

Route::get('/Visitor/index', VisitorController::class);

Route::get('/care', fn()=>Inertia::render('care'));

Route::get('/appearance', fn()=>Inertia::render('appearance'));

Route::get('/info', fn()=>Inertia::render('info'));

Route::get('/inventory', fn()=>Inertia::render('inventory'));

Route::get('/varities', fn()=>Inertia::render('varities'));
```

Comment: Логично. `Route::get('/Visitor/index', VisitorController::class);` => `form.post(route('Visitor/index'))`, ошибка дело говорит, post Visitor/index не существует, есть get

Comment: Route существует в web.php "Route::get('/Visitor/index', VisitorController::class);", я просто забыл написать это тут

Comment: Но в web.php это GET роут, а Вы во vue кидаете POST запрос...

Comment: Я попробовал поменять что там что нам запрос на post, ничего не помогло, поменял на get тоже самое. Ошибка в обоих случаях одинаковая

Comment: Смотрите что во vue возвращает route('Visitor/index'), в laravel - php artisan route:list ищите точно этот же роут

Comment: POST            Visitor/index ...................................................................................... Pages\VisitorController
Вот что пишет за роут в php artisan route:list

form.post(route('Visitor/index'))
Вот в vue
Я может что-то не понимаю но мне кажется они одинаковые

Comment: Так нельзя invoke и другие методы использовать вместе. В том коде который вы прислали нет post маршрута. Должно быть определено Route::post(....) Второе. в методе invoke указан Visitor $visitor. Откуда он взялся? когда в урле в принципе нет ключа {visitor}. Уверен для ваших целей просто подойдет ресурсный маршрут. создайте через make: ресурсный контроллер и в роуте вызовите так: Route::apiResouce('visitors', VisitorController::class); и всё заработает. на фронте вызываете так: route('visitors.store') если post или route('visitors.index') если гет и так далее.

Comment: Чтобы не путаться в урлах правильная практика именовать все маршруты. и обращаться к ним по имени, тогда будет меньше ошибок